# How can I use Istio to create service aliases?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

According to the [Istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#virtual-services), VirtualServices should be able to route requests to "a completely different service than was requested". I would like to use this feature give services different aliases in different applications.

I'm starting with a VirtualService definition like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - my-alias
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: my-service
```

The intention is that a client pod in the mesh should be able to send requests to http://my-alias and have them routed to my-service. In the future I'll expand this with match rules to make the alias behave differently for different clients, but even the simple version isn't working.

With no other setup, the client fails to resolve my-alias via DNS. I can solve this by adding a selectorless k8s service named my-alias so its DNS resolves, but then the VirtualService doesn't seem to do the redirect. If I add an external host like google.com to the VirtualService, then it does successfully redirect any requests to google.com over to my-service. Using the full hostname (my-alias.default.svc.cluster.local) doesn't help.

So it seems like the VirtualService is not allowing me to redirect traffic bound for another service in the mesh. Is this expected, and is there a way I can work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I was using unnamed ports for my services, so traffic never made it into the mesh. According to https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/, the HTTP port must be named `http`.

Comment: do you have the simple example available? i'm struggling with the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to rewrite `authority` (the HOST header) of your request, since the HTTP routing in Istio is performed by the HOST header.

Add an [HTTPRewrite](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#HTTPRewrite) clause to the `http` clause:

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - my-alias
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: my-service
    rewrite:
      authority: my-service`

Comment: I ended up getting it working without having to rewrite the authority. Rewriting is probably a good idea though, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right approach but using `Istio` `1.7.4` with `Minikube` it works.

Setup the `default` namespace to enable automatic Istio Injection:

```sh
export ISTIO_BASE_DIR=~/istio-1.7.4

kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled

kubectl -n default apply -f ${ISTIO_BASE_DIR}/samples/sleep/sleep.yaml

kubectl -n default wait pod -l app=sleep --for condition=Ready
```

Istio Objects:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin-alias
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: httpbin.org
  ports:
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: httpbin-org-se
spec:
  hosts:
  - httpbin.org
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https-port
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: httpbin-org-dr
spec:
  host: httpbin-alias.default.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: tls-origination
    trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
      portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 443
        tls:
          mode: SIMPLE
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin-org-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - httpbin-alias.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 80
    rewrite:
      authority: httpbin.org
    route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin-alias.default.svc.cluster.local
        subset: tls-origination
        port:
          number: 443
```

The test:

```sh
export SOURCE_POD=$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})

kubectl exec "${SOURCE_POD}" -c sleep -- curl -is http://httpbin-alias.default.svc.cluster.local/get
```

The result:

```sh
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Sat, 31 Oct 2020 12:51:11 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 1340
server: envoy
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1096

{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.69.1", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5f9d5dbf-56498e4e1fb660062264a9ce", 
    "X-B3-Sampled": "0", 
    "X-B3-Spanid": "def6fd9e5a97df39", 
    "X-B3-Traceid": "88eeed562ce0c692def6fd9e5a97df39", 
    "X-Envoy-Attempt-Count": "1", 
    "X-Envoy-Decorator-Operation": "httpbin-alias.default.svc.cluster.local:443/*", 
    "X-Envoy-Peer-Metadata": "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", 
    "X-Envoy-Peer-Metadata-Id": "sidecar~10.32.0.10~sleep-854565cb79-lx6nv.default~default.svc.cluster.local"
  }, 
  "origin": "187.20.35.178", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Log of `istio-proxy` container into `sleep` POD:

```
[2020-10-31T13:18:23.261Z] "GET /get HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-" 0 1340 811 810 "-" "curl/7.69.1" "a168f9d8-c9b4-4a5d-9312-715f47e220da" "httpbin.org" "35.170.225.136:443" outbound|443|tls-origination|httpbin-alias.default.svc.cluster.local 10.32.0.10:41666 54.156.97.186:80 10.32.0.10:55648 - -
```